# How to repeat a string 'x' times given 'y' parameters

Tags: string, generator, combinations

I need to repeat 19 strings like the following to generate a sitemap; mysite.com/especialidad/policia. I need to combine it with 60 parameters like ?region=madrid, ?region=barcelona.

So I need to generate 19*60 (1140) like mysite.com/especialidad/policia/?region=barcelona.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you tell us what tool/language you intend to use?  The answer will likely be language-specific.

Comment: I don't know which language to use. But I can work in Javascript and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP**:

```
$myArray = ( "madrid", "barcelona", "...");
foreach($myArray as $e) {
   echo "mysite.com/especialidad/policia?region=".$e;
}
```

**Java**:

```
String[] myArray = {"madrid", "barcelona", "..."};
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("mysite.com/especialidad/policia?region="+myArray[i]);
}
```

**Python**:

```
myArray = ['madrid', 'barcelona', '...']
for e in array:
   print 'mysite.com/especialidad/policia?region=',e
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var index;
var myArray = ["madrid", "barcelona", "..."];
for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++) {
    console.log('mysite.com/especialidad/policia?region='+a[index]);
}
```

**Perl**:

```
my @myArray = ("madrid", "barcelona", "...");
foreach (@myArray) {
  print "$_<br>\n";
}
```